# Difference between resource and resources methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

What is the logical difference between `resource` and `resources` methods

Here is some examples:

```
resource :orders, :only => [:index, :create, :show]

> rake routes
 orders POST       /orders(.:format)            orders#create
        GET        /orders(.:format)            orders#show


resources :orders, :only => [:index, :create, :show]

> rake routes
 orders GET        /orders(.:format)            orders#index
        POST       /orders(.:format)            orders#create
  order GET        /orders/:id(.:format)        orders#show


resource :orders

> rake routes
     orders POST       /orders(.:format)            orders#create
 new_orders GET        /orders/new(.:format)        orders#new
edit_orders GET        /orders/edit(.:format)       orders#edit
            GET        /orders(.:format)            orders#show
            PUT        /orders(.:format)            orders#update
            DELETE     /orders(.:format)            orders#destroy


resources :orders

> rake routes
     orders GET        /orders(.:format)            orders#index
            POST       /orders(.:format)            orders#create
  new_order GET        /orders/new(.:format)        orders#new
 edit_order GET        /orders/:id/edit(.:format)   orders#edit
      order GET        /orders/:id(.:format)        orders#show
            PUT        /orders/:id(.:format)        orders#update
            DELETE     /orders/:id(.:format)        orders#destroy
```

It looks like method `resource` does not create route for `index`, and helpers in some cases are different (new_order and new_orders). Why?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Actually you are right, `resource` should not create an index action, unless you ask for the index action explicitly, this way:

```
resource :orders, :only => [:index, :create, :show]
```

Helpers should differ too, but not that much as in your example, because the convention is to use a singular form with the `resource` method, and the plural with the `resources`

```
resources :orders
=> rake routes

     orders GET        /orders(.:format)            orders#index
            POST       /orders(.:format)            orders#create
  new_order GET        /orders/new(.:format)        orders#new
 edit_order GET        /orders/:id/edit(.:format)   orders#edit
      order GET        /orders/:id(.:format)        orders#show
            PUT        /orders/:id(.:format)        orders#update
            DELETE     /orders/:id(.:format)        orders#destroy

resource :order
=> rake routes
      order POST       /order(.:format)            orders#create
  new_order GET        /order/new(.:format)        orders#new
 edit_order GET        /order/:id/edit(.:format)   orders#edit
            GET        /order/:id(.:format)        orders#show
            PUT        /order/:id(.:format)        orders#update
            DELETE     /order/:id(.:format)        orders#destroy
```

And the logical difference is to declare you logically can't have the plural for resource in your app, for example Admin or whatever

Comment: i think you mean the first line to say `resource :orders, :only ...`

Comment: "Helpers should differ too": it means that you get `new_order_path` for `resources` and `new_orders_path` for `resource`.

Comment: The main difference is not just index page.

-- **resources** will create routes with index page and also will require :id parameter to edit, update, destroy and show   actions ([Check]http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use)


-- **resource** will create the same routes without index route and without required :id param. ([Check] http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources)

Answer (score 97):

At a high level, the intent of `resource` is to declare that only one of these resources will ever exist. For example:

```
resource :profile, :only => [:edit, :update]
```

As a user, I should only be able to update my own profile. I should never be able to edit other users' profiles, so there's no need for a URL scheme like `/users/1/profile/edit`. Instead, I use `/profile/edit`, and the controller knows to use the current user's ID rather than the ID passed in the URL (since there is none).

That's why you don't get an `index` action with `resource`: there's only one resource, so there's no sense in "listing" them.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for this illuminating explanation. So this means we have profile controller which will be different from a users controller? Also if I want the url to look like `/profile/settings`, I can use `collection { get 'settings' }`