# handling one-to-one user relations with controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been wondering if there is any better way to handle one-to-one relations with Rails.

I have a User model, which has_one Subscription. When the user is logged in, I get the subscription by retreiving current_user.subscription, so that finding subscriptions by id in URL is unncessary.

Right now, when user wants to update his subscription, he gets the url:
/subscription/3/?plan_id=2

But the subscription 3 is unncessary, and the other thing is I don't want to be showing the number of subscriptions (ids) to the user.

Whats would be a better solution for this? Would you guys bother with that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your routes.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `resource :subscriptions` (not resources). As described here ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194767/difference-between-resource-and-resources-methods))
the difference is, that `resource` doesn't create an index route (only if you say explicitly that you want one) and doesn't need IDs in the url

Quote from the linked answer:

> At a high level, the intent of resource is to declare that only one of
>   these resources will ever exist. For example:
>
> resource :profile, :only => [:edit, :update] As a user, I should only
>   be able to update my own profile. I should never be able to edit other
>   users' profiles, so there's no need for a URL scheme like
>   /users/1/profile/edit. Instead, I use /profile/edit, and the
>   controller knows to use the current user's ID rather than the ID
>   passed in the URL (since there is none).
>
> That's why you don't get an index action with resource: there's only one resource, so > there's no sense in "listing" them.

Answer (score 1):

I guess You have something like this defined in Your routes

```
resources :subscriptions
```

What You want is a collection level custom action which is defined like this:

```
resources :subscriptions do
  get 'new_plan', on: :collection
end
```

Now You will need to add an action in You controller of the same name. And the link to get there will be:  `/subscription/new_plan?plan_id=2`