# rails resource method name difference from model name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

Does the resource name have to be plural ('resources :articles' )  When you define a resource inside the route.rb? If so,  does the name of model need to be the same but in singular form so the model table will match the resources since rails will convert it to plural.

Or it doesnt really matter? I am so confused...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between resource and resources methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194767/difference-between-resource-and-resources-methods)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a simple Google search could answer this question. Or reading through the Rails docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the resource name have to be plural

Not always! You can declare [***singular resources***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) as well. But the *resource name* should match the *controller name* not the *model name*. You should read [***Resource Routing***](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default) to understand better

As per the convention, the *model name* should always be ***singular*** and Rails by default looks for ***plural form*** of the *model name* in the table.

Comment: I think less formatting will make the post more readable. When everything is highlighted/emphasized, nothing is.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how does it look now?

Comment: Better. I'd still drop italics on bold and links. They stand out enough already.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I got habituated to it :)